# Partitions of the set of vertices of a directed graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Consider a directed graph and a partition $P$ of its set of vertices. We construct a new partition $P'$ of this set as follows: declare $v_1$ and $v_2$ to be in the same part of the partition $P'$ if for every $p\in P$, $v_1$ arrows into $x\in p$ for some $x$ iff $v_2$ arrows into $y\in p$ for some $y$. The problem is to prove or give a counterexample to the statement that the finer the original partition is, the finer the new partition will be. (By finer I mean either the same or strictly finer.)

I haven't been able come up with a counterexample, so I'm trying to prove this. Suppose this is false. Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two partitions. Denote by $P_i'$ the corresponding new partition. By assumption, $P_2'$ is not finer than $P_1'$. So there is $x\in P_2'$ such that for all $y\in P_1'$ it is not the case that $x\subset y$. I need to show that then there is $X\in P_2$ such that for all $Y\in P_1$ it is not the case that $X\subset Y$. But I don't quite understand how to use the definition of the new partition to deduce this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a direct proof is more simple than a proof to the contrary. Assume that $P_2$ is finer than $P_1$. Consider any $p’_2\in P_2’$. Let $v,u\in p’_2$ be any vertices and $p_1\in P_1$ be any element. If $v$ arrows to $x$ for some $x\in p_1$ then, since $P_2$ is finer than $P_1$, there exist $p_2\in P_2$ with $x\in p_2\subset p_1$. Since $v,u\in p’_2$, there exists $y\in p_2\subset p_1$ such that $u$ arrows to $y$. Similarly we can show that if $u$ arrows to $x$ for some $x\in p_1$ then there exists $y\in p_1$ such that $v$ arrows to $y$. Thus $v$ and $u$ are in the same part of the partition $P’_1$. So $P’_2$ is finer than $P'_1$.

Comment: What definition of "$P_2$ is finer than $P_1$" are you using? I thought it means that every element of $P_2$ is a subset of some element of $P_1$. But it looks you're using another definition. Is your definition equivalent to the above?

Comment: (Addition to the above: you must be using the definition in line 3 and in the last line, and I don't quite understand what's the definition that you are using and what exactly you are proving.) And could you clarify how this follows: "since $u,v\in p_2'$, there exists $y\in p_2\subset p_1$ such that $u$ arrows to $y$"? Also, you write "if $v$ arrows to $x$" or "if $u$ arrows to $x$", but what if not?

Comment: @user638943 1. Yes, I use the same definition as you. 2. Since $v$ arrows to $x$, $x\in p_2$, and $v,u\in p’_2$, by definition of $P’_2$, $u$ arrows to $y$ for som  $y\in p_2$. 3. In order to show that $v$ and $u$ are in the same part of the partition $P’_1$ we have to sheck that for every $p_1\in P_1$, $v$ arrows into $x\in p_1$ for some $x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $u$ arrows into $y\in p_1$ for some $y$. When we consider $v$ arrows to $x$, we show $\Rightarrow$, when we consider $u$ arrows to $x$, we show $\Leftarrow$.